# Please help! Error: The value of the property 'Menu_Unhover' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I would appreciate it if someone could help me out here.

I have a global navigation bar that I'm using in SharePoint 2010. Every time I apply this script, I get the following error messages whenever I mouseover/mouseout of the menu. The console gets terribly junked up with these error messages, and unfortunately in IE8, it shows an error on the page. I need to get rid of them.

> Line: 1 Error: The value of the property 'Menu_Unhover' is null or
>   undefined, not a Function object
>
> Line: 1 Error: The value of the property 'Menu_HoverDynamic' is null
>   or undefined, not a Function object
>
> Line: 1 Error: The value of the property 'Menu_HoverRoot' is null or
>   undefined, not a Function object

Here's my code.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
/*
Format for extendedTabs:
extendedTabs(tabSide, TitleTabName, urlTab, ListName, listSiteURL)
TabSide: prepend, adds tab to the global navigation bar
TitleTabName: Display name of tab in the global navigation bar
urlTab: url which tab name links to, example: http://www.google.com
listName: Name of list that maintains the links displayed under that tab
listSiteURL: url to SharePoint site where list for that tab is maintained, Do not include /Lists/ in the URL
*/
    extendedTabs('prepend', ' HQ', '', 'GlobalNav_HQ', 'http://mysite/');
    extendedTabs('prepend', 'Organizations', '', 'GlobalNav_Orgs', 'http://mysite/');
    extendedTabs('prepend', 'Communities', '', 'GlobalNav_Communities', 'http://mysite/');
    extendedTabs('prepend', 'Tools', '', 'GlobalNav_Tools', 'http://mysite/');
    extendedTabs('prepend', 'Leadership', '', 'GlobalNav_Leadership', 'http://mysite/');
    extendedTabs('prepend', ' Support', '', 'GlobalNav_Support', 'http://mysite/');

var i = 1; 
function extendedTabs(tabSide,titleTabName,urlTab,listName,listSiteURL) { 
//alert("IN FUNCTION");
var titleTabID = 'zz1_New_TopNavigationMenun' + titleTabName.replace(/[-' ']/g,'');
var showTabPD = titleTabID + 'Show';
var showTabAppend = titleTabID + 'Append'; 
//alert("URLTAb "+urlTab);
if (urlTab != '') {
var urlTabShow = 'href=' + urlTab;
} else {
var urlTabShow = '';
}
var tableRow = '<td id="' + titleTabID + '" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onmouseover="Menu_HoverRoot(this)" class="Tab-Outer-Container"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="" class="ms-topnav zz1_TopNavigationMenu_4"><tbody><tr id="mouse"><td style="white-space: nowrap;"><a ' + urlTabShow + ' style="" class="zz1_TopNavigationMenu_1 ms-topnav zz1_TopNavigationMenu_3">' + titleTabName + '</a><td valign="top" style="width:0pt;" ><img style="border-style:none; vertical-align:top;" alt="" src="http://mysite//GlobalNavScripts/dropDown.png"></td></tr></tbody></table><div style="position:absolute;height: 0px;z-index:1;"><div id="' + showTabPD + '" class="zz1_TopNavigationMenu_8" style=""><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="top: 0px;" id="' + showTabAppend + '"></table></div></div></td>';
//alert("tblRow: "+tableRow);
if (tabSide == 'append') {
$('table#zz1_New_TopNavigationMenu').children().children().prepend(tableRow);
} else {
$('table#zz1_New_TopNavigationMenu').children().children().append(tableRow); 
} 
$().SPServices({ 
operation: "GetListItems", 
webURL: listSiteURL, 
listName: listName, 
completefunc: function (xData, Status) { 
//alert(xData.responseXML.xml);
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode('z:row').each(function() { 
var URLdataTN1 = $(this).attr("ows_URL").split(','); 
//alert("URL "+URLdataTN1);
var linksTN1 = $(this).attr("ows_LinkType"); 
//alert(linksTN1);
if (linksTN1 == 'Header') {
    $('#' + showTabAppend).append('<tr id="zz1_New_TopNavigationMenun' + i + '" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)"><td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" class="ms-topNavFlyOuts zz1_TopNavigationMenu_7 ms-topNavFlyOutsHover"><tbody><tr><td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 100%;"><a style="" class="zz1_TopNavigationMenu_1 ms-topNavFlyOuts zz1_TopNavigationMenu_6 ms-topNavFlyOutsHover"><strong>' + URLdataTN1[1] + '</strong></a></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>');
//$('#' + showTabAppend).append('<tr id="zz1_New_TopNavigationMenun' + i + '" ><a style="border-style: none; font-size: 1em;" class="zz1_TopNavigationMenu_1 ms-topNavFlyOuts zz1_TopNavigationMenu_6 ms-topNavFlyOutsHover"><strong>' + URLdataTN1[1] + '</strong></a></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>');
i++; 
} else if (linksTN1 == 'Header Link') { 
$('#' + showTabAppend).append('<tr id="zz1_New_TopNavigationMenun' + i + '" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)"><td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" class="ms-topNavFlyOuts zz1_TopNavigationMenu_7 ms-topNavFlyOutsHover"><tbody><tr><td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 100%;"><a style="" href="' + URLdataTN1[0] + '" class="zz1_TopNavigationMenu_1 ms-topNavFlyOuts zz1_TopNavigationMenu_6 ms-topNavFlyOutsHover"><strong>bbb' + URLdataTN1[1] + '</strong></a></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>'); 
i++; 
} else { 
//alert("0: "+URLdataTN1[0]+"1: "+URLdataTN1[1]);
$('#' + showTabAppend).append('<tr id="zz1_New_TopNavigationMenun' + i + '" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)"><td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" class="ms-topNavFlyOuts zz1_TopNavigationMenu_7"><tbody><tr><td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 100%;"><a style="" href="' + URLdataTN1[0] + '" class="zz1_TopNavigationMenu_1 ms-topNavFlyOuts zz1_TopNavigationMenu_6">' + URLdataTN1[1] + '</a></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr>');
i++; 
} 
}); 
} 
}); 
$('#' + titleTabID).mouseover(function(){ 
$('#' + showTabPD).show(); 
});
$('#' + titleTabID).mouseleave(function(){ 
$('#' + showTabPD).hide(); 
}); 
} 
});
```

The odd thing about this is that it does not impede functionality. Also, this error message, although showing up on all browsers, is only most prominent on IE8, which displays an "Error on page" message at the bottom left hand corner of the page.

I've already tried different things, such as JS file order, performing try/catch statement (which doesn't work on this either), and have Googled this extensively without any results. I even tried suppressing the errors, which works, but that's not optimal.

I'd greatly appreciate any assistance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling functions that doesn't seem to exist in this line (and in some other lines as well):
You must either declare the functions or remove the eventhandlers that calls the undefined functions.

```
var tableRow = '<td id="' + titleTabID + '" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onmouseover="Menu_HoverRoot(this)" class="Tab-Outer-Container"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="" class="ms-topnav zz1_TopNavigationMenu_4"><tbody><tr id="mouse"><td style="white-space: nowrap;"><a ' + urlTabShow + ' style="" class="zz1_TopNavigationMenu_1 ms-topnav zz1_TopNavigationMenu_3">' + titleTabName + '</a><td valign="top" style="width:0pt;" ><img style="border-style:none; vertical-align:top;" alt="" src="http://mysite//GlobalNavScripts/dropDown.png"></td></tr></tbody></table><div style="position:absolute;height: 0px;z-index:1;"><div id="' + showTabPD + '" class="zz1_TopNavigationMenu_8" style=""><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="top: 0px;" id="' + showTabAppend + '"></table></div></div></td>';
```

Comment: I admit I am not a JS expert; if you don't mind, can you provide me with an example of what you mean by either declaring or removing the functions? Is the onmouseout, onkeyup examples of functions in this line?

Comment: Go through your script. Everytime you see something like onmouseout="Menu_Unhover();" that is an event that calls a function called "Menu_Unhover" if this particular function is not defined then you will get an errror everytime the mouse out event ocours. A function definition for the event in this example will look like this: function Menu_Unhover() {//some code to execute;} In your submitted code none of the functions that is causing the errors seems to be declared.

Comment: Since you script seems to be working even with undeclared functions I think it is safe to remove the events that calls the undeclared functions. eg removing onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)"

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Your answer was the right one. When I removed those undeclared functions, all the errors disappeared! Before I mark it as the answer, let me move it to production just to make sure, and then I'll update this thread.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick!

For anyone in the future, here's what I removed:

From:
onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" 
onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" 
onmouseover="Menu_HoverRoot(this)"

To:
onkeyup="" 
onmouseout="" 
onmouseover=""

Comment: Happy to be able to help. :)